# Data not returned in variable using Laravel's View Composer

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, crud

I'm using view composer in Laravel as follows:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use App\Models\Green;
use App\Models\Blue;

class SidebarServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot(): void
    {

       View::composer('layouts.sidebar', function ($view) {

            $dataGreen = Green::all();
            $dataBlue = Blue::all();

            $view->with([
                'green' => $dataGreen,
                'blue' => $dataBlue
            ]);

        });
    }
}
```

Then I added my provider to the array:

```
App\Providers\SidebarComposerServiceProvider::class,
```

But I get the following framework error when I try to return a data with `@foreach`

```
Undefined variable $dataGreen
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the variables you are returning in the view composer are `$green` and `$blue`, not `$dataGreen` & `$dataBlue`, as they're declared variables within the function's scope.